# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty | x'(x_n) | < \infty$ for all $x' \in X'$ then $\sup_{\|x'\| \leq 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty | x'(x_n) | < \infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have this question to solve, but I have no idea how to solve:

a) Let $X$ a normed space and $\{ x_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ a sequence with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty | x'(x_n) | < \infty$ for all $x' \in X'$. Show that $\sup_{\|x'\| \leq 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty | x'(x_n) | < \infty$.

b) Let $K \subset C([a,b])$ be $K = \{ f \in C([a,b]) : \int_{a}^{(a+b)/2} f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{(a+b)/2}^{a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x \}$. Show that $K$ is a closed vector subspace and find $x' \in C([a,b])'$ so that $\ker (x')=K$.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Define a linear map
$T:X'\to\ell^1$, by
$$
T(x')=(x'(x_n))_n.
$$
The Closed Graph Theorem can then be used to show that $T$ is bounded, from where one deduces that
$$
\infty > \|T\| =
\sup_{\|x'\|\leq1} \|T(x')\| = $$$$=
\sup_{\|x'\|\leq1} \sum_n|x'(x_n)|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

(a) Without loss of generality, we may assume that $X$ is complete.
For, if $X$ is not complete, let $\bar{X}$ be its completion. Note
that every bounded linear functional defined on $X$ has a unique
continuous extension on $\bar{X}$. Hence $x'\in X^{\ast}$ can be
regarded as a bounded linear functional on $\bar{X}$. Moreover, the
norm of $x'$ remains the same after extension. We also recall that the canonical
embedding $X\rightarrow X^{\ast\ast}$, $x\mapsto\hat{x}$, where
$\hat{x}(f)=f(x)$, $f\in\hat{x}$, is a linear isometry, i.e., $||\hat{x}||=||x||.$

Let $\mathcal{C}=\{\alpha = (\alpha_n)\in\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}\mid|\alpha_{n}|=1\}$
be the collection of all $\mathbb{C}$-valued (or $\mathbb{R}$-valued,
depending on the scalar field of $X$) sequences $\alpha=(\alpha_{n})$
that satisfies $|\alpha_{n}|=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ For each
$\alpha\in\mathcal{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $\theta_{\alpha,n}\in X^{\ast\ast}$ by $\theta_{\alpha,n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}\hat{x}_{k}.$
For each $f\in X^{\ast}$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
|\theta_{\alpha,n}(f)| & = & \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}f(x_{k})\right|\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|f(x_{k})\right|\\
 & := & M_{f}\\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\{\theta_{\alpha,n}(f)\mid n\in\mathbb{N},\,\,\alpha\in\mathcal{C}\}$
is bounded. By Uniform Boundedness Principle, $\eta:=\sup_{\alpha,n}||\theta_{\alpha,n}||<\infty.$
We go to show that $\sup_{||f||\leq1}M_{f}<\infty$ by contradiction.
Suppose the contrary that $\sup_{||f||\leq1}M_{f}=\infty$, then there
exists $f\in X^{\ast}$ with $||f||\leq1$ such that $M_{f}>\eta+1$.
Hence, there exists $n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|f(x_{k})\right|>\eta+1.$
For each $k$, choose $\alpha_{k}\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha_{k}|=1$
such that $|f(x_{k})|=\alpha_{k}f(x_{k})$. Define $\alpha=(\alpha_{k})\in\mathcal{C}$.
Now we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\eta+1 & < & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|f(x_{k})\right|\\
 & = & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}f(x_{k})\\
 & = & \theta_{\alpha,n}(f)\\
 & \leq & ||\theta_{\alpha,n}||\cdot||f||\\
 & \leq & \eta,
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

(b) To ease discussion, without loss of generality, we assume that
$a=-1$ and $b=1$. Let $K=\{f\in C[-1,1]\mid\int_{-1}^{0}f=\int_{0}^{1}f\}$.
Let $K^{\bot}=\{\mu\in(C[-1,1])^{\ast}\mid\mu(f)=0 \mbox{ for all } f\in K\}.$

We assert that:

(i) $K$ is a a closed subspace of $C[-1,1]$, where $C[-1,1]$ is
equipped with the supremum norm.

(ii) $\mu\in K$ iff $\mu$ is a finite signed measure on $([-1,1],\mathcal{B}([-1,1]))$
and there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(A)=c\cdot\lambda(A\cap[-1,0])-c\cdot\lambda(A\cap[0,1])$,
where $\lambda$ is the usual Lebesgue mearsure, or in short $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x)=h_{c}(x),$
where $h_{c}=c\cdot1_{[-1,0]}-c\cdot1_{[0,1]}.$

Proof: (i) Clearly $K$ is a vector subspace of $C[-1,1].$ Let $(f_{n})$
be a sequence in $K$ and suppose that $||f_{n}-f||\rightarrow0$
for some $f\in C[-1,1]$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{-1}^{0}f\\
 & = & \lim_{n}\int_{-1}^{0}f_{n}\\
 & = & \lim_{n}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}f.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $f\in K$. Hence, $K$ is closed.

(ii) Define a map $\theta:C[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\theta(f)=\int_{-1}^{0}f-\int_{0}^{1}f$.
Define $\iota:[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\iota(x)=x$. Observe
that for each $f\in C[-1,1]$, $f+\theta(f)\iota\in K.$

Let $\mu\in K^{\bot}$. By Riesz Representation Theorem, $\mu$ is
a finite signed measure on $([-1,1],\mathcal{B}([-1,1]))$ and for
any $f\in C[-1,1]$, $\mu\left(f+\theta(f)\iota\right)=0$, i.e.,
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}fd\mu=-\theta(f)\mu(\iota).
$$

Let $a,b$ be arbitrary such that $-1\leq a<b\leq0$. Choose a sufficiently
large $N\in\mathbb{N}$. For $n\geq N$, define
$$
f_{n}=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{if }x\in[-1,a]\\
n(x-a) & \mbox{if }x\in(a,a+\frac{1}{n})\\
1, & \mbox{if }x\in[a+\frac{1}{n},b]\\
1-n(x-b), & \mbox{if }x\in(b,b+\frac{1}{n})\\
0, & \mbox{if }x\in[b+\frac{1}{n},1]
\end{cases}.
$$
Clearly $f_{n}\in C[-1,1]$ and $f_{n}\rightarrow1_{(a,b]}$ pointwisely
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. (Note that the graph of $f_{n}$ is a trapezium
with two sharp edges). Hence, $\int_{-1}^{1}f_{n}d\mu=-\theta(f_{n})\mu(\iota).$
Note that $|f_{n}|\leq1$ and $1$ is $\mu$-integrable. By Dominated
Convergence Theorem and letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we obtain $\mu\left((a,b]\right)=c(b-a)$,
where $c=-\mu(\iota)$. Let $\mathcal{P}=\{(a,b]\mid-1\leq a<b\leq0]\}$
and $\mathcal{L}=\{A\in\mathcal{B}((-1,0])\mid\mu(A)=c\cdot\lambda(A)\}$.
Clearly $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-class and $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-class
and $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{L}$. By Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$
theorem, we have $\sigma(\mathcal{P})\subseteq\mathcal{L}$ and hence
$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{B}((-1,0])$. It can be proved similarly that
$\mu(\{-1\})=0$. Now, it follows that if $A\in\mathcal{B}([-1,0])$,
then $\mu(A)=c\cdot\lambda(A).$ Arguing in the same way, we can also
prove that for any $0\leq a<b\leq1$, $\mu\left([a,b)\right)=-c(b-a)$.
By invoking Dynkin's theorem again and observing that $\mu(\{1\})=0$,
we have: $\mu(A)=-c\cdot\lambda(A)$ for any $A\in B([0,1])$. Finally,
if $A\in B([-1,1])$, we have (observe that $\mu(\{0\})=0$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu(A) & = & \mu\left(A\cap[-1,0]\right)+\mu\left(A\cap[0,1]\right)\\
 & = & c\cdot\lambda\left(A\cap[-1,0]\right)-c\cdot\lambda\left(A\cap[0,1]\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Conversely, if $\mu$ is a finite signed measure and there exists
$c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(A)=c\cdot\lambda\left(A\cap[-1,0]\right)-c\cdot\lambda\left(A\cap[0,1]\right),$
it is trivial to verify that $\mu\in K^{\bot}.$

Comment: Update: Once we have arrived the step $\int_{-1}^{1}fd\mu=-\theta(f)\mu(\iota)$,
we are done and there is no need to invoke Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$
Theorem.

For, denote $c=-\mu(\iota)$ and define a signed measure $\nu$ by
$\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(x)=h_{c}(x)$, where $h_{c}(x)=c\cdot1_{[-1,0]}-c\cdot1_{[0,1]}.$
Observe that $-\theta(f)\mu(\iota)=\int_{-1}^{1}fd\nu$. Hence, we
have $\int_{-1}^{1}fd\mu=\int_{-1}^{1}fd\nu.$ Since it is true for
all $f\in C[-1,1]$, it follows that $\mu=\nu$.